# Export Outlook Emails Into SQL (Vai ACCESS?)

Tags: sql-server, outlook, office365

I have a email folder in Outlook that contains 100s of emails which record my discussions with a developer of some bespoke software. I want to import these into SQL to create a knowledge base of information that can be searched upon to extract all the decisions that we have made during the course of the 2 year project.

Having sreached the net, I found that it is very easy to dump the contents of an email folder into Access using the import data functionality. In fact I have linked the table and so believe (never used Access before!!) that I now have an Access table that is connected in 'real-time' to the Outlook folder. This is eactly what I want BUT in SLQ as this is something that I am very familiar with using.

So I have tried to import the Access database into SQL (which also appears to be relatively easy) but keep getting the message that 'The source database ...contains no visible tables or views'. Checking SQL pemissions, I am owner of this new databse.

Two questions please. First, cant believe that going through Access is the simplest way to do this and presume that I will loose the 'real-time' link - am I right? Second, given that I can see my Access database has a visible table, why am I getting the error?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest way is to create a VBA macro where you can populate your SQL database from Outlook emails. You can build the table structure according to your needs and extract the required information from Outlook using VBA. I'd suggest processing emails in chunks using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class, so you will not reach the reference counter limit. The [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) properties you may find described in MSDN.

BTW The internal store (if you use the cached mode) in Outlook acts like a database. So, why do you need to introduce yet a new database?